# Compute the loss of a moving dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mnist, spatial-transformer-network

I’m new to the world of machine learning, so it could be that my question is trivial or incorrectly posed.

I am using a moving dataset that I have forwarded to an STN network (Spatial Tranformation Network). To the STN I forward each image individually, then restack the whole images together in a tuple.
My problem lies in the loss calculation. My target has a torch.tensor with this size [2,1,64,64]
and my prediction that I want to implement has a torch.tensor [2,1,10,64,64], which means that the prediction and the target are not the same.
Could someone explain an idea to me. The only idea I have is to return the last STN output meaning something like this [2,1,1,64,64] to my prediction and then squeezed to be [2,1,64,64] and then calculate the loss.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you explain what type of problem you are dealing with (classification?). And provide the meaning for each dimension of your tensors (both prediction and label tensor).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My goal is to produce a gif with the moving dataset after applying some distortion using STN. So i don't thing that i need a classifier here.

Comment: Can you provide the meaning of each dimension of your tensors (both prediction and label tensor).

Comment: Hey @Ivan the sequence of frames has the dimension:  [ number of batches , number of channel, number of frame, height , width]. What the end goal will be is to see when a frame consists of 2 or more digits  could the the affine_grid function generate some spatial transformation networking on every digit in the image or not.

Comment: @ivan The tested idea was to split the video with 10 frames into 10 tensors.
every tensor will be squeezed due to the fact that every frame has this tensor format[num_batches, num_channel, num_frames, height, width]
Each tensor has this format: [num_batches, num_channels, height and width as passed to the STN function. 
After that, my idea was to compare the last frame with the target frame, that is, to calculate the loss depending on the target frame and the target.
This means that the loss is calculated depending on the target image and the last transformed image, which makes no sense.